# what are the differecnes between these two managed properties; Description & DescriptionOWSMTXT

Tags: development, search, managed-property, content-search-web-part, crawled-property

I am building a Content Search Web Part, and inside this Content search web part i want to show the list items Description. so inside the Content Search web part i found these 2 managed properties :-

- Description
- DescriptionOWSMTXT

so not sure what are the differences between them , now seems the `Description` is linked to many crawl properties and it is querable, while the `DescriptionOWSMTXT` is linked to a single crawled property and it is not querable, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce on these:-

1. if i want to show the Description of my issue tracking list which one i need to use?
2. now i tried adding these two managed properties inside my content search web part, but i got empty result?? so why the two fields do not show the related description (regardless which one i need to use)!!

Answer (score 0):

I always just try them and see what comes back (I use the diagnostics display template and dump all the managed properties in there).

I think M is multi lines of text, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The DescriptionOWSMTXT is multiple lines text description only (MTXT stands for multiple lines text.)

The Description is the normal description with office:6; which is Description, DocComments, and ExcludedFromSummary.

The Description is probably what you are looking for, but as Eric said, I usually use [SharePoint Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) to make sure that's what I want.